# How to use solve this using a subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Please consider the following tables:

```
Table Name: Person   
Person_Id   Name 

Table Name: DVD    
DVD_ID  Owner_ID  Title
```

I want a query that returns the list of DVDs that belong to owners who own “Superman”. Here is my solution:

```
SELECT p.name,d.dvd_id
FROM  DVD d,Person p
WHERE p.person_id = d.dvd_id
AND Title = 'Superman' ;
```

My interviewer was expecting me to use a subquery. Is that possible? Is my query the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    DVD 
where 
    Owner_ID=(select Person_Id from Person where Name='Superman')
```

Given name superman is unique.

Answer (score 2):

Hope so, This will help you.

```
select dvd_id 
from DVD 
where Owner_ID in 
(select person_id 
 from person 
 where name = 'Superman')
```

using `=` where i used `in` will also help in same way.